# emails from localhost using mocksmtp

Tags: email, localhost

I have been trying to setup email on my local machine. After some advice that it is a rather involved thing to set up, I started to look around for a solution to my problem and came across an app called `mocksmtp`. I have followed [this tutorial](http://dlmax.org/blog/setting-up-mocksmtp-on-osx-10-7lion-for-local-php-development) to set it up. But i'm getting errors.

of

`send-mail: warning: valid_hostname: invalid character 64(decimal): my.email@address.com
send-mail: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: my.email@address.com`

Looking at [this page](http://www.netdip.com/virtualmin-myhostname-bad-parameter-value-error-solved-1tp/) I believe the problem is with `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

`myhostname = my.email@address.com`

but what value should I change the email address to to make this work? I have tried a few option but nothing has worked for me and in that post the only problem was a period at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is a valid and helpful page and would have worked perfectly had telnet localhost 1025 been enabled. Enabling telnet got it working. To do this `telnet localhost 1025` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to enter an entire email in a parameter meant only for a host name. You should only have address.com, not my.email@address.com. It's not for a full email. You're setting this up as a server, to catch everything for a host, not just one particular email.